# Why  Oracle’s driver doesn’t  support READ_UNCOMMITTED?

Tags: oracle

Why doesn’t Oracle’s driver support READ_UNCOMMITTED?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [Tom Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65asktom-082389.html):

> The READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level allows dirty reads. Oracle
>   Database doesn't use dirty reads, nor does it even allow them. The
>   basic goal of a READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level is to provide a
>   standards-based definition that allows for nonblocking reads. As
>   you've seen, Oracle Database provides for nonblocking reads by
>   default.

Answer (score 4):

Because the Oracle database doesn't support the ability to read uncommitted data.  Given Oracle's multi-version read consistency architecture where readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers, I'm hard pressed to come up with a situation where you'd want to read uncommitted data.  In other databases, that can be a way to minimize locking at the cost of consistency but there is no locking in Oracle in order to read only committed data.